# Make Nautilus navigate to the first file beginning with the typed letter

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

When I hit <kbd>N</kbd> in Nautilus under a folder, it behaves like I am searching files which contains `N`. Can I make it so that it only leads me to the first file whose name starts with `N`, like Windows Explorer?

Comment: Have you considered porting Windows Explorer?

Comment: Nope...I just used to doing it this way while under `Windows`, `Ubuntu` and `Linux Mint`, when there is a large amount of files in one folder.

Comment: See related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275883/traditional-search-as-you-type-on-newer-nautilus-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I press the letter <kbd>N</kbd> in a folder in Nautilus that contains files whose names start with a letter <kbd>N</kbd> it jumps to the first one of these files. Pressing it a 2nd time will begin the search by name (a little box pops up in the lower right hand corner).

There isn't a way to change this behavior using Nautilus. I believe you can use other file explorers though such as [`mc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) (aka. midnight commander - terminal based) or [Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/) (KDE).

There's a pretty extensive list of [file explorers on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers). Check out the section of [*nix ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers#.2Anix-only_file_managers) for other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04**

As the type-ahead search was a Ubuntu-specific patch, it got dropped together with Unity in 17.10. However, there is a package called [`nautilus-typeahead`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nautilus-typeahead/) in the Arch repository. Someone took it, compiled for Ubuntu and made a PPA. You can install it by these three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead
sudo apt dist-upgrade
nautilus -r
```

There is [an issue on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1767431) about bringing this behavior back to official Ubuntu.
The original answer that I found during the search [Traditional search-as-you-type on newer Nautilus versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/278553/573344).

Tip: Check the answer link above if your OS older than **Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04**

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that if you **go to `nautilus => preferences` and disable `Search in Subfolders`** it works as expected.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work on 22.04. Which version of Nautilus are you using?

Comment: I don't use nautilus anymore, so I can't remeber which version I was using at this time :/